# Distinct in r within groups of data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, distinct, transformation

How do I transform a dataframe (on the left) to dataframe (on the right)?

[image]

I am trying to do this via dplyr, by grouping into name and distinct, but it gives only 3 rows

```
df %>%
group_by(name) %>%
distinct(.,keep.all = T) %>%
View()
```

Comment: Why would you want to delete information from your data? Or do you only want to display your data in the way to the right of your image?

Comment: I would want it in that format for a different purpose, this is just a minimal example representing the logic I want. I would want to download the right dataframe as a csv

Comment: It is not quite clear to me, what exactly you're looking for. 
I also could not reproduce your code, in the sense that I got the full dataframe as a result. (Using Name in the group_by call and not name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to access all the cells you want to change:

```
data <- data.frame(name = c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 5), rep("C", 5)), subject = c(rep(1:5, 3)), marks = sample(1:100, 15))

> data
   name subject marks
1     A       1    31
2     A       2    12
3     A       3    29
4     A       4    67
5     A       5    99
6     B       1    77
7     B       2     3
8     B       3    92
9     B       4    69
10    B       5    42
11    C       1    52
12    C       2    66
13    C       3    98
14    C       4    23
15    C       5    72
```

`duplicated(data$name)` accesses the relevant cells. But `R` has no way to leave a cell "blank", so to speak.

You can either set them `NA`, or fill it with an empty `character`:

```
data$name[duplicated(data$name)] <- NA

> data
   name subject marks
1     A       1    31
2  <NA>       2    12
3  <NA>       3    29
4  <NA>       4    67
5  <NA>       5    99
6     B       1    77
7  <NA>       2     3
8  <NA>       3    92
9  <NA>       4    69
10 <NA>       5    42
11    C       1    52
12 <NA>       2    66
13 <NA>       3    98
14 <NA>       4    23
15 <NA>       5    72
```

---

```
data$name <- as.character(data$name)
data$name[duplicated(data$name)] <- ""

> data
   name subject marks
1     A       1    30
2             2    52
3             3     5
4             4    48
5             5    99
6     B       1    14
7             2    20
8             3    34
9             4    55
10            5    53
11    C       1    38
12            2    27
13            3    67
14            4    12
15            5    77
```

---

To use the latter solution with a `factor` variable, you need to add `""` as a factor label:

```
data$name <- factor(as.numeric(data$name), 1:4, c(levels(data$name), ""))
data$name[duplicated(data$name)] <- ""
```

Comment: This looks a very good way to achieve what i want, thanks a lot for the quick response.